# How to delete files matching pattern within a directory

Tags: delphi

That is, delete all files matching pattern within a given directory

Example,  Delete all *.jpg files within DirectoryName

Comment: You could use a regular expression.  Do some googling for pattern matching, RegEx isn't my speciality but they are powerful as hell.

Comment: (File apis usually don't support regexes, just plain wildcards. Full regex is more something for shells and scripting languages)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DeleteFiles(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)),'*.jpg');
end;

procedure DeleteFiles(APath, AFileSpec: string);
var
  lSearchRec:TSearchRec;
  lPath:string;
begin
  lPath := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(APath);

  if FindFirst(lPath+AFileSpec,faAnyFile,lSearchRec) = 0 then
  begin
    try
      repeat
        SysUtils.DeleteFile(lPath+lSearchRec.Name);    
      until SysUtils.FindNext(lSearchRec) <> 0;
    finally
      SysUtils.FindClose(lSearchRec);  // Free resources on successful find
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: (There is no need to fillchar the lsearchrec)

Comment: Thanks all. This is exactly what i eas looking for.

Comment: *Always* do a FillChar if you want to program properly. This may do nothing, but this is a good habit to keep. One day if you program in C like I did you'll get in *big* trouble if you did not have good habits. You *always* have to suppose the record is uninitialized and you *always* should imagine that the memory may not be always set with 0 bytes. You really have to put the FillChar function back, to show others good habits instead of bad ones.

Comment: You don't always need to FillChar, but I never remember which APIs need it or not. I just prefer to do it all the time myself.

Comment: Shouldn't the FindClose be in a finally clause?

Comment: Changed code to correctly free resources only when a find is successful.

Comment: This routine works perfectly, though the compiler wants to wrap `lPath+lSearchRec.Name` with `PWideChar(lPath+lSearchRec.Name)`. Thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 13):

In more recent versions of Delphi, you would probably use the classes in `System.IOUtils`, which are essentially wrapping `FindFirst`, `FindNext` etc:

```
procedure DeleteFilesMatchingPattern(const Directory, Pattern: string);
  var FileName: string;
begin
  for FileName in TDirectory.GetFiles(Directory, Pattern) do TFile.Delete(FileName);
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the SHFileOperation function.  The nice thing about using SHFileOperation is you have the option of deleting the files to the recycle bin and you get the normal API animations so the user will know what is going on.  The downside is the delete will take a little longer than Jeff's code.

There are several wrappers out there.  I use this free wrapper from BP Software.  The entire wrapper file is only 220 lines and is easy to read and use.  I don't install this as a component.  I have found it easier to add this unit to my project and just Create and free the object as needed.

Update: The download link for the BP Software site is no longer valid.  There is an [older version on the Embarcadero website](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/15248).

> TSHFileOp (1.3.5.1) (3 KB) 
> May
>   31, 2006 
> TComponent that is a wrapper
>   for the SHFileOperation API to copy,
>   move, rename, or delete (with
>   recycle-bin support) a file system
>   object.

The file name parameter for SHFileOperation supports MS DOS style wildcards.  So you can use the component like this:

```
      FileOps := TSHFileOp.Create(self);

      FileOps.FileList.Add(DirectoryName + '\*.jpg');

      FileOps.HWNDHandle := self.Handle;
      FileOps.Action := faDelete;
      FileOps.SHOptions :=
          [ofAllowUndo, ofNoConfirmation, ofFilesOnly, ofSimpleProgress];
      FileOps.Execute;
```

I usually show the "Are you sure" message myself so I always pass the ofNoConfirmation flag so Windows does not ask again.

If you don't want to delete every jpg file or you need to delete from multiple directories you can add full file names or different paths with wild cards to the FileList string list before calling execute.

Here is the [MSDN Page for SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164(VS.85).aspx)
Note that SHFileOperation has been replaced by IFileOperation starting with Windows Vista.  I have continued to use SHFileOperation on Windows Vista without any problems.

Comment: Thank you this another fair solution and doc - i did try it with the TSHFileOp wrapper.